# How to deploy Angular App to Offline server

Tags: angular, deployment

I have an Angular application that I need to deploy to a test server.

I generated it with this command:

`ng build --configuration production`

Then updated this line of index.html as follows:

`<base href="/myapp/">`

And copied the content of the \dist folder to the \webapps Tomcat folder in the test server.

When I try to access the application I'm getting this error in Chrome Dev Tools:

`GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I believe this is happening because the Test Server doesn't have connection to the internet.

Then, when Angular tries to download the fonts at runtime it cannot find it.

The server will not be connected to the internet by design.

So how can I generate the \dist with all of Angular dependencies, such as those fonts and all other files that Angular would need, so that it works in a server without internet connection?

Comment: remove the link and install the font as dependencies. check fontsource.org `npm install @fontsource/roboto`

Comment: @SO is full of Monkeys Yes, I could bypass this error downloading and installing the fonts in the app and deploying them to the server. Just didn't use this npm process. Downloaded and installed them directly updating index.html and styles.css to reference them instead of remote version.